# I can't write to the external SD card(extSdCard) in Android Studio

Tags: android

I have created an android app that needs to create a folder and write text files on my external SD card(extSdCard). I am using the Galaxy S4 device and have written the following codes for that. I already know the path of /mnt/.. file and have created a string for it. The android manifest.xml file uses the permission.i have checked the codes in "adb logcat" in Cmd prompt and it does not give any error but doesn't create any folder. The device has also been checked unconnected with the PC. Would appreciate if you help me. Here is the code.

```
    String externalFilePath="/mnt/extSdCard/tmp";

            Log.d(TAG, "externalFilePath is: "+externalFilePath);

            File myfile = new File(externalFilePath, "Hello");
```

Comment: don't use hard coded path, and also make sure you have permissions...  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Which version of android are you using? KitKat doesn't allow this, however lollipop seems to have brought it back.

Comment: I had added the permission. I can create the folder in the device storage but not on sdcard, although it is writable. Do you mean the phone device has also teh Kitkat or lollipop version? I thought only this is for the simulators.

Comment: Does my answer helped you?

Answer (score 4):

First of all make sure that you have this line inside your `manifest,xml`, somewhere outside `application` tag.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Then you can write a `File` doing this :

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File(sdcard.getAbsolutePath() + "/tmp/");
// creates if doesn't exists
dir.mkdir();
// create a File
File file = new File(dir, "Example.txt");
FileOutputStream os = outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
//this is the text that will be inside of the Example.txt
String data = "Hello world";
os.write(data.getBytes());
os.close();
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

try this code to generate files under your application package

```
File path = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
```

// Replace DIRECTORY_PICTURES with your needs

```
    File file = new File(path, "Hello");
```

Also make sure you have added the permissions

Comment: It doesn't give error but still doesn't make any folder this way. I have seen the options for Environment instead of DIRECTORY_PICTURES, seems that they refer to  internal device storage as options like downloads, documents, etc.